# Issue on IE7 when page is scrolling.Text is not proper

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing this issue on IE7 only, when I am scrolling the page: Text of some section is not scrolling properly, although a horizontal line is scrolling.

May be it's a loading issue but I need to solve this.

Technology is HTML5, bootstrap, CSS3. Framework is MVC.

[image]

Look at the `Search Again` text in the image above.

Comment: pls show code or site link.......

Comment: At least some code in the question, and possibly a http://jsfiddle.net or link to live scenario, otherwise not a real question.

Comment: i m creating the link for people.As i cant display the website url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a the IE7 Text Redraw bug:

http://zomigi.com/blog/ie-7-button-text-redraw-bug/

http://www.lifeathighroad.com/web-development/fixed-ie7-button-text-redraw-bug/

try adding this to the button css:

```
overflow: visible
```

If that doesn't work try this:

```
border: 1px solid transparent;
```

Comment: Hey ya ites ie7 bug and i am using html5 button tag but i am changing it to <a> tag its working fine ? is this buttn tag issue or wt ?

Comment: yes, problem is with the button element, so changing to an <a> tag would be a round-a-bout way of fixing it!

Comment: You most likely have some styles or markup which are triggering the bug. If you are interested in further reading on the subject then this is a very detailed post: http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/