# JQuery UI draggable element leaves weird traces in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I'm trying to make my first chrome extension here.It's a sticky note board. But when I try to drag the first element on my board using JQueryUI it leaves horizontal lines as traces in chrome.

Here's a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Here's is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Sticky notes using CSS3 and Google Fonts (Step 5)</title>
<link  href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reenie+Beanie:regular" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<style type="text/css">

body{
  font-family:arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:100%;
  background:#666;
  color:#fff;
}
h2,p{
  font-size:100%;
  font-weight:normal;
}
ul,li{
  list-style:none;
}
ul{
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:3em;
}
ul li div{
  color:#000;
  background:#ffc;
  min-height:10em;
  min-width:10em;
  padding:1em;
  -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
  -moz-transition:-moz-transform .15s linear;
  -o-transition:-o-transform .15s linear;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .15s linear;
}
ul li{
  margin:1em;
  float:left;
}
ul li h2{
  font-size:140%;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
ul li p{
  font-family:"Reenie Beanie",arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:180%;
}
ul li div{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-6deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-6deg);
}
ul li:nth-child(even) div{
  -o-transform:rotate(4deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(4deg);
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  background:#cfc;
}
ul li:nth-child(3n) div{
  -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  position:relative;
  top:-5px;
  background:#ccf;
}
ul li:nth-child(5n) div{
  -o-transform:rotate(5deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(5deg);
  position:relative;
  top:-10px;
}
ul li div:hover,ul li div:focus{
  box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);
  position:relative;
  z-index:5;
}
ol{text-align:center;}
ol li{display:inline;padding-right:1em;}
ol li div{color:#fff;}
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="step.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="step1.html">Step #1</a></li>
    <li><a href="step2.html">Step #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="step3.html">Step #3</a></li>
    <li><a href="step4.html">Step #4</a></li>
    <li><strong>Step #5</strong></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  </ol>
  <ul>
    <li >
      <div class="dragable">
        <h2>Title #1</h2>
        <p >Text Content #1</p>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="dragable">
        <h2>Title #2</h2>
        <p>Text Content #2</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="dragable">
        <h2>Title #3</h2>
        <p>Text Content #3</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="dragable">
        <h2>Title #4</h2>
        <p>Text Content #4</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="dragable">
        <h2>Title #5</h2>
        <p>Text Content #5</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="dragable">
        <h2>Title #6</h2>
        <p>Text Content #6</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="dragable">
        <h2>Title #2</h2>
        <p>Text Content #2</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="dragable">
        <h2>Title #7</h2>
        <p>Text Content #7</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="dragable">
        <h2>Title #8</h2>
        <p>Text Content #8</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

and the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $(".dragable").draggable().bind('click', function(){
          $(this).focus();
        });
    });

    $('.dragable').bind('click', function() {
        $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    }).blur(
        function() {
            $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'false');
        });
})
```

Note: After some experimentation I found that the problem is with -webkit-transform
If I comment them out, the problem doesn't show up.

Comment: its somthing like which i face few days back in ie7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315896/issue-on-ie7-when-page-is-scrolling-text-is-not-proper/12316442#12316442  just try this may be you will get your solution

Comment: @SACHIN: that applies to IE7, the OP is asking about Chrome..

Comment: i knw bt i am saying try this thing for crome coz problem is same :-)

Comment: I experienced the same with animation keyframes lately in chrome.

Comment: @Christoph did you find a solution? if you did please help :(

Comment: @tarashish I wish i had :-/ I just hope this will get fixed sometime in the next versions as it's not to urgent for me.

Comment: Manually doing `$('body').css('background','#666');`
redraws the background , but pragmatically doing the same doesn't work :(

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Finally I have a working workaround .

Just using
 `outline: 1px solid transparent;` 
on the div fixes the problem :)

It's an anti-aliasing issue.

Comment: This worked for me as well. A little note to other people that might have this problem: If you have a radius bigger than 1px, set the outline to something bigger than the radius.
And also, this didn't work for me if adding a box-shadow

Comment: The problem in chrome seems to appear when setting the width/height to a non integer. Rounding off values seems to be a better fix for me. (otherwise I would need yet another encapsulating div to my animated content to add a colored-border)

Answer (score 0):

Its a crome redraw bug

http://blog.andrewcantino.com/blog/2012/02/15/fixing-the-chrome-background-refresh-bug/

have a look on this may be you will get your sloution.

Comment: well it works fine on jsfiddle ..so how can i show the demo ? I have pasted the code above and a screenshot too.